# org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for SampleRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http

I am new to Sping Boot and I am trying to call External POST API using RestTemplate but getting error No HttpMessageConverter for SampleRequest.

Below is my Controller class I have also tried converting the message but it did not helped me.

Controller Class :

```
import com.SampleRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public class TicketAgentController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TicketAgentController);

@PostMapping(path = "/TicketAgent", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public String createTroubleTicket(@RequestBody SampleRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {

    //Move to Common and service
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());


    final String baseUrl = "http://172.100.5.89:8095/api/Ticket/v2";
    URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    LOGGER.info("Start ..");

    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, String.class);

    LOGGER.info("Result :" + result);
    LOGGER.info("End ..");

    return result;

}

//Move to Common
private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = 
      new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    return converters;
}

}
```

Exception After running :

> 2019-12-17 12:11:38.943 ERROR 9240 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No
>   HttpMessageConverter for com.SampleRequest with root cause
>
> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No
>   HttpMessageConverter for com.SampleRequest    at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:964)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:717)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:443)
>   ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]

Let me know if I need to provide anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestTemplate does not know anything about your object SampleRequest and its serialization.
I think the simplest way to use ObjectMapper:

```
...
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
var entity = new HttpEntity<>(mapper.writeValueAsString(request), headers);
var result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, entity, String.class);
...
```

You can Autowire ObjectMapper mapper or create new one.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks that helped me I got an Exception Though "No serializer found for class com.SampleRequest and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)"  I have done mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);  and it worked, can you please suggest what actually this error means.

Comment: Usually if POJO/DTO/Entity is used in serialization process (serialized into json), this object is decorated with json framework's annotations (simpler and faster than to use own serializer). The most popular framework if fasterxml. You can add class annotations JsonInclude, JsonIgnoreProperties, JsonPropertyOrder and fields annotation JsonProperty. In this case the serialization (and deserialization) processes are easier and more proper.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue on debugging I found that I haven't defined getter methods for the sample request pojo which were leading me to the same error.